# Read HTTP POST request from file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read HTTP post request stored in a file then send it via python socket, the problem is that post body is not read by the webapp, is there any trick to cosider when sending HTTP requests from a low-level ?

Code snippet :

```
f = open('req.txt', 'rb')
req = f.read()
f.close()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, 80))
s.send(req)
s.close()
```

req.txt :

```
POST /api HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
Connection: close
Cookie: nothing
Content-Lenght: 11

param=value
```

Comment: First, is `req.txt` using `\r\n` line breaks, and doing so consistently? HTTP/1.1 allows (but doesn't require, or even recommend) servers to accept `\n` line endings, and most of them do—but if you inconsistently mix the two (especially if you use `\r\n` in the headers but then `\n` for the blank line between the headers and the body), many of them will not tolerate that.

Comment: If not, the most likely problem is that you misspelled `Content-Length`. Many servers, if they don't see a `Content-Length`, will just read until EOF, but some servers will not, and will instead assume there is no body at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `Content-Length`.

According to [HTTP/1.1 (RFC7230)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3), given that this is a request message, and does not have a `Transfer-Encoding` header, having no `Content-Length` header means that the body length is 0.

The rules are actually a bit more complicated than that (follow the link), and many servers bend over backward to be tolerant of clients that break the rules—but this is probably why the webapp framework is ignoring the body rather than passing it on to your app.